# How to get a white circle with a black border using "Graphics"?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want a white filling inside the black dot

```
  Graphics[{Black, FillingStyle -> White, PointSize[0.035], Point[{1, 2}]}]
```

Comment: Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Disk[{1,2},0.035]}]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Point` doesn't have a distinction of interior and edge. Use `Disk` instead:

```
Graphics[
  {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[White], Disk[{1, 2}, Scaled[0.035]]}
]
```

[image: a dot with white interior and black edge]

Answer (score 4):

Use a Disk instead of a Point.

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[White], Disk[{1, 2}, 0.035]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {1, 3}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Graphics[{Circle[], Annulus[{1, 2}, {0.02, .035}]}]
```

[image]